# How to change domain for my assets in tapestry

Tags: tapestry

By default; the domain of all assets( js, css) is fixed which is the current domain. In order to improve the speed of website; we want to retrieve all assets using subdomain assets.example.com instead of example.com.

I checked http://tapestry.apache.org/assets.html ; where for "New domains" it is specified as

> If you wish to create new domains for assets, for example to allow
>   assets to be stored on the file system or in a database, you may
>   define a new AssetFactory and contribute it to the AssetSource service
>   configuration.

This was not exactly helpful as to exactly what I should do !

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the [`AssetPathConverter`](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/AssetPathConverter.html). As the documentation states

> The default implementation of this is identity, the URI is passed
>   through unchanged. Using a contribution to the ServiceOverride
>   service, you may override the default implementation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks interesting.. I am new to tapestry. How can I use it in my existing code where we already have all Assets defined and which have default URI.