# Changing the domain of a virtual asset in Tapestry 5.1

Tags: assets, tapestry

Using the approach suggested in the answer to this question: [How to change domain for my assets in tapestry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230945/how-to-change-domain-for-my-assets-in-tapestry), one can change the domain of static assets. I would however like to change the domain of the combined an minified JavaScript files generated by Tapestry, so that I can use CloudFront to cache these files. Unfortunately, the above solution does not work for virtual assets.

The only solution I could think of, is implementing my own MarkupRenderingFilter and rewriting the resource URI there. Are there any more elegant approaches?